# Como paginar en PHP con MVC?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, model-view-controller

Tengo un controlador y una vista que funcionan perfectamente, lo encontré en internet pero ahora quisiera paginar los registros y no consigo realizarlo con MVC:

**Controlador**

```
class Home

{

public function saludo($nombre)    {

    View::set("name", $nombre);

    View::set("title", "Custom MVC");

    View::render("home");

}



public function users()

{

    $users = UserAdmin::getAll();

    View::set("users", $users);

    View::set("title", "Custom MVC");

    View::render("users");

}

}
```

**Vista**

```
<tbody>

            <?php

            foreach ($users as $user)

            {

            ?>

            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $user["id"] ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $user["nombre"] ?></td>

            </tr>

            <?php

            }

            ?>

        </tbody>
```

**Este es el modelo**

```
class User
{

public static function getAll()
{

    try {

     $connection = Database::instance();

     $sql = "SELECT * from usuarios";

     $query = $connection->prepare($sql);

     $query->execute();

     return $query->fetchAll();

    }
    catch(\PDOException $e)

    {
     print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();

 }
```

Comment: Podríamos ver el código del Modelo?

Answer (score 1):

primero, debes obtener mediante parámetros de url la página en la que estás y en base a esto, paginas los usuarios. Por ejemplo:

en el controlador, debes recuperar las variables de paginación (`page` y `qty`, si es que deseas ambas):

```
public function users() {
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
    $qty = 10; // o $_GET['qty'] si quieres que sea parametrizable

    $users = UserAdmin::getAll($page, $qty);

    View::set("users", $users);

    View::set("title", "Custom MVC");

    View::render("users");
}
```

Luego en tu modelo, debes limitar tus resultados a la cantidad deseada, con un offset de `cantidad * (pagina - 1)`:

```
public static function getAll($page = 1, $qty = 10){
  try {
    $connection = Database::instance();

    $sql = "SELECT * from usuarios LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";

    if($page <= 0) $page = 1;  

    $query = $connection->prepare($sql, array($qty, $qty * ($page-1)));

    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();

  } catch(\PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```